# Use WP7 XNA Library in WP7.1 XNA Project as refrence

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I have a game library that made for WP7. i want to use it in my Mango Project but when i added library's refrence (as project refrence) to mango project, show this message: "A refrence to 'MyLibrary' could not be added. Refrences with different refresh are not supported."
how can i update my library for use in Mango projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the project (in Solution Explorer) and select the option to upgrade it to 7.1